# SQLite cursor.getCount() > 0 but cursor.moveToFirst() returns false

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working with SQLite database in android for a project.
I have made many tables and I am fetching data from them.
But I don't know why this table shows `CURSOR_COUNT` of 7. The `if` condition of `cursor.moveToFirst()` returns `false` every time and I am getting log of else part.

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM `profile_pic`", null);
Log.e("CURSOR_SIZE", String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));

   if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
       if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
          //some code here...
       } else {
           Log.e("DATABASECURSORRRR123123", "ELSE PARTghdgdfgdfgdfgdfg");
       } 
   } else {
        Log.e("ELSE", "TRUE");
}
```

Comment: Guess: Your table contains data where the rows are >2MB in size.

Comment: Yes, Thank you so much. I was getting images from local db. Instead of storing the link of image i was trying to store whole encoded image.